# Django Postgres objects.create ValidationError

Tags: python, django, postgresql

How do you sync Django's ids with Postgres without losing data?

I somehow got Django into a weird state where I can no longer create objects. A call to:

`Chapter.objects.create(title = 'hello')`

throws the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "genesis_chapter_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.
```

`title` is not a unique field. How is this even possible? I suspect Django has gotten out of sync with Postgres and tried to assign a used id, but I've done nothing more special than make calls to `objects.create`. I've used only the Django ORM. How could that ever get Django out of sync?

Comment: `title` is not a unique field

Comment: Could you provide your models?

Comment: There are four models. Here's the psql output.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-lNrhyIv47CRGE4eXdqdFA2Vzg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Why the downvote? Off-topic? Unclear?

Comment: I meant the django models code

Comment: the primary key '2' is being attempted to be used again.
i really don't use create()
new_chapter = Chapter(title='hello')
new_chapter.save()

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-lNrhyIv47CYjFCU1dpRXU3ZXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's right. This error was generated by a call to `objects.create` without specifying the key. Why Django doesn't know to use a different key?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't apply because I never migrated from a different database. In fact, I've only made database calls through the Django ORM. Never messed with the database directly.

Answer (score 0):

try

new_chapter = Chapter(title='hello')

new_chapter.save()

Comment: can you do a 'describe'  '\d chapter_chapters'?
and post that here.
also could you try insert into chapter_chapters (title) values ('hello');

Answer (score -1):

I guess the issue is with how you defined id while its creation in postgresql. You should have defined id element type as `serial` for auto increment.